# Can't reach JSON-data in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backend, resultset

I've been using JSON-files and can read them without problems on the front-end. But now I tried sending some data from the client to the server and am getting some problems:

This is the JSON being sent:

```
  myJSON = {
    "name": activeTeam.name,
    "testing": "tehTeSttTT"
  }
  myJSON = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
```

This is the backend (Node.js):

```
console.log("\nThe JSON resultset: " + data);

console.log("\nThe TEST: " + data.testing);
```

And this is what the back-end console writes out:

```
The JSON resultset: {"name":"hAHHAdhaHAHDashda","testing":"tehTeSttTT"}

The TEST: undefined
```

How come "testing" is 'undefined'? It seems to not be undefined looking at the JSON resultset. Usually I just reach the objects in the json using ".object" but it doesn't seem to work for me in the backend.

Comment: Your data might still be in string form,  try  `data  = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Thanks alot! I first tried this on the client side before sending, but tried it on the server side after I read your comment. Obviously that's where it was needed.

Comment: you want to transmit JSON (which is a string) - then to use it, you parse it where you need it - because you can't transmit javascript objects (easily)

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Jaromanda X. Makes sense.